# Can't Understand What Is the issue?

Tags: php, curl, basic-authentication

I am just trying to get some data from my created api. whenever i am trying to get data from it. it shows me error message of my api. here is the code, please help me.

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "My/Url/Call",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic YXNoaXNoQGNyZW9sZXN0dWRpb3MuY29tOkNyZW9sZUAxMjM="
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

Is is because i am using basic authentication?

Comment: And the error your getting is....?

Comment: it's my api error. that invalid method called.